# CSS Selector :focus not working with Chromecast

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus, chromecast

I am trying to adapt an HTML based app for Chromecast and everything is working fine, except that the ":focus" is not taken into account in the CSS.

I am using it to display differently some items (basically the equivalent of the "selected item").

The focus is handled properly (calling ".focus()" on some DOM node works fine), just the display is not done properly.

I suspect this could be intentional as there is no keyboard and such for Chromecast. I could always rewrite the whole CSS to add a "focused" class on the element, but rewriting the whole thing just for Chromecast as it is already working on a number of platforms seems a bad idea.

Is there a way to activate the support for ":focus" in the CSS ?
Is there a work around ?

Best Regards

JN

Comment: Will the functionality of the site not work without the CSS you have on that :focus? If its just for visual effect, I'd say keep it as is.

Comment: No, it is not just for visual effect. The user interaction is "broken" because the user does not know the "current video" playing in the list that is shown on the screen, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the chromecast is not to have a UI in the way that you are describing; the "control/navigation" is on the second screen and the consumption of content (playback of media, for example) is on TV. As an example, consider the Google Play Music. User picks up her mobile device, navigates through albums and such on her device till she finds the desired content. During this interaction, the TV screen doesn't try to show the navigation that is happening on her device and that makes sense since she is not even looking at the TV; in fact, it would have been pretty difficult to look at TV (assuming it was mirroring her mobile display) and navigate on her mobile device; user doesn't want to move her eyes from one to the other while she is searching through her content. Finally when she finds what she casts that to TV and can listen to that on her TV. It is the same behavior with the TV and Movies app, Netflix and Hulu+ as well and it is strongly recommended you follow the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that idea and what I am doing is to have the whole navigation happening on the mobile device, which I think is the beauty behind chromecast. I would also like to reflect on TV some information and the existing HTML/CSS is using ":focus" to so. So, I just want to do "myCurrentVideo.focus()" and have it look like it is selected. The same indication will be reflected on the mobile/tablet as well and the navigation will occur there.

Is it completely impossible to do with ":focus" or is there a way to activate it ? (can be desactivated be default)